# Looping through xml to get element/ node to update one element

Tags: java, mysql, xml

So I am trying to get a particular xml node of deductible from a string value of the full XML. I'm trying to replace the string inside of the node with a variable and I'm not having any luck doing it.

The code bellow should supply what I have tried.

```
 private String updateXMLDeductible(String Deductible, String xml) {
            try {
                XmlHelper newxml = new XmlHelper();
                Document doc = newxml.loadDoc(xml);
                Node newel = null;

                XPath xpath = new XPath("/location/location/deductible");
                newel = (Node) xpath.selectSingleNode(doc);
                newel.setTextContent(Deductible);
}
```

The result Id like is to set the string value of deductible to my passed in deductible.

Comment: There is no looping here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an object that reflects your xml schema using JAXB. Unmarshal it. This will return your java object.Change the value in your java object. Then marshal it to back to a String (that is your xml) if you need.

For example

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "YourXMLRootElement") //name is not required if it class name is the same as YourXMLRootElement which I'm assuming is location
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyObject{
  public MyObject(){
  /**
    *JAXB requires empty constructor
    */
  }

  @XmlAttribute(name = "deductible")//name is not required if same as attribute name
  private String deductible;
  //getter and setter


  //other attributes with getters and setters
}
```

```
private String updateXMLDeductible(String deductible, String xml) {
  MyObject myObject= JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml), MyObject.class);
  myObject.setDeductible(deductible);
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  return JAXB.marshal(myObject,stringWriter);
}
```